# Symfony 3 and EasyAdminBundle: Form's text field don't work properly

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.2, symfony2-easyadmin

I'm going to working in a Admin Backend to a WebPage with Symfony 2.2.8 and Javier Eguiluz's EasyAdminBundle 1.16.12 (last version). I installed the bundle following the instructions in GitHub page, and I have also created a couple of test entities (Users and Engagementes).

Well, my trouble is that the text type in the edit template not working, they are empty and without label, otherwise the entity can be edited correctly.

User:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="User")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="surname", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $surname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=50, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="role", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $role;

// getter and setter [...]
```

Engagement:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Engagement
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Engagement")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\EngagementRepository")
 */
class Engagement
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=20, unique=true)
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="owner", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $owner;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="phone", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="incident", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $incident;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="brand", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $brand;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="model", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $model;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="repairer", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $repairer;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cost", type="float", nullable=true)
     */
    private $cost;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="advance", type="float", nullable=true)
     */
    private $advance;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="start_date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $startDate;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="comment", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $comment;

// setters and getters [...]
```

Config.yml:

```
# [...]
easy_admin:
    entities:
        - AppBundle\Entity\User
        - AppBundle\Entity\Engagement
```

And I get it with EasyAdminBundle:

[image: Engagemente Edit]

[image: Engagemente List]

P.S.: I'm sorry if I made mistakes, English is not my native language.

Comment: Well, At end it was a noob error, I had a global twig theme, one was causing me troubles.